# Script en Python duda

Tags: python, script

Estoy aprendiendo Python, y quiero expresar la siguiente formula pero no logro escribirla bien, me ayudan por favor?

La formula es: (1 + raiz cuadrada de 5)/2

Hago lo siguiente pero me da error:

```
ratio = ((1+(5**(1/2))/2)
print(ratio)
```

¿Cual es el error?

Comment: Paréntesis mal balanceados.

Answer (score 2):

El error que tiene es uno muy común al empezar el proceso de aprendizaje en muchos lenguajes de programación.

Y es que cuando usamos los paréntesis tan seguido es normal perder la cuenta de cuantos hemos abierto o cerrado, en tu caso tienes un paréntesis sin cerrar y por eso el error que te da, solo agregarlo al final y ya funciona.

Ya que estás en una etapa de aprendizaje te recomiendo [www.codewars.com](http://www.codewars.com) ahí puedes practicar tus habilidades con ejercicios que suben según tu nivel, y comparar las soluciones que tengas con personas de muy alto nivel y sus soluciones.

Comment: Genial!! Muchas gracias!! Seguiré tu recomendacion :)

Comment: También se puede configurar el IDE para que destaque el otro par de un paréntesis, "[", "{", etc. Muy útil para ver si todo está balanceado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es un truco que suena bastante util! Trataré de configurarlo asi entonces. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un paréntesis.
También puedes usar la función sqrt del modulo math
Para sacar la raíz cuadrada.

Ejemplo:

from math import sqrt

raiz = sqrt(5)

radio =  (1 + raiz )/ 2

print(radio)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte! Me resulta muy importante saber esta otra forma. Saludos!